# Parameter has already been defined error message when defining parameters in for loop before SQL insert query

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to parameterise the query in the `for loop`, but VS2013 keeps telling me that the parameter has already been defined (and always points to the parameters in the for loop).

Any reason why this keeps happening?

```
var query =
    "INSERT INTO booking (operator_id, plot_id, postcode, reference) " +
    "VALUES (@operator_id, @plot_id, @postcode, @reference);";

for (var i = 0; i < _waypointList.Count; i++)
{
    query +=
        "INSERT INTO waypoint (booking_id, sequence, address, lat, lng, reference) " +
        "VALUES ((select id FROM booking WHERE reference=@reference), " +
        "@sequence, @address, @lat, @lng, @reference)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@reference"), _reference);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@sequence"), i);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@address"), _waypointList[i]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@lat"), _lat);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@lng"), _lng); 
}

Console.WriteLine(query);
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DbConnect.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@operator_id"), _operatorId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@plot_id"), _plotId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@postcode"), _postcode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@reference"), _reference);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbConnect.CloseConnection();
```

Comment: cmd is declared outside of the for loop; on each iteration you're redefining it.  Move definition & execution inside the loop.

Comment: this code needs some serious refactoring / rethinking .. you code looks like it will cause more bad than good.. also remove that `query+=` the error is telling you exactly what's wrong.. you already added it in the first iteration.. so adding the same parameter in the 2nd iteration will fail.. use the debugger also here is a good link to read 
[C# Basics Tutorial - Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm) if you are trying to execute 2 Inserts.. separate / use the IDE to `refactor` some of that code into a Method

Comment: I have a list of waypoints that I am trying to add in, is there a different way of approaching this. I would appreciate your help

Comment: what is the cmd.CommandType lol put code like this into a stored procedure also you are not showing the full method signature.. and yes there is a much better way of doing that .. where are you defining your paramvalues? show all relevant code please

Comment: @MethodMan - I didn't realise I could do that, I've been doing this all long :-(. Can you please show me an example?

Comment: you have the `IDE` you highlight over the code you want to extract into a method, select `Refactor---> ExtractMethod` I think that you need to seriously draw out on paper what it is you're trying to do then write out the code / process flow for that.. you're trying to do too much and it's causing you to get all mixed up.. respectfully speaking

Comment: another option is to pass in a `List<T>` as a parameter and create a method that does the Insert using a `foreach` loop so many ways and or options on this one.

Comment: I didn't know how to implement what you suggested MethodMan, but now I'm getting a `operator_id` not defined error message. Please help me. I have been working on this all day with little success. I've made my code available here: http://pastebin.com/nkLRCmbZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding multiple times parameters with the same name. If _waypoinList have 5 elements you will add 5 parameters with name reference,sequence, address, lat and lang. Because of that you have the exception.

I don't know why you are doing this, I don't see the point of this code, but the easiest solution is to call `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` in the begging of the loop or if you want to have different parameter for each iteration of the loop you need to write it like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < _waypointList.Count; i++)
    {
        query +=
            @"INSERT INTO waypoint 
                 (booking_id, sequence, address, lat, lng, reference) 
             VALUES 
                  ((select id FROM booking WHERE reference=@reference" +  i.ToString() + @"),
                  @sequence" + i.ToString() + @", 
                  @address" + i.ToString() + @", 
                  @lat" + i.ToString() + @", 
                  @lng" + i.ToString() + @", 
                  @reference" + i.ToString() + ")";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@reference" + i.ToString()), _reference);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@sequence" + i.ToString()), i);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@address" + i.ToString()), _waypointList[i]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@lat" + i.ToString()), _lat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@lng" + i.ToString()), _lng); 
    }
```

In this case you will guarantee unique parameter names for every iteration.

Comment: I am getting the error message  @reference0 must be defined.

Comment: this should add cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@reference" + i.ToString()), _reference); the @reference0. Also you can debug it.

Comment: This is my code here - http://pastebin.com/C2BTQrHW. I've debugged and it appears to do everything right but it is still throwing an error message at me in the console as seen at http://imgur.com/1hK7lBF

Comment: I'm now getting an `@operator_id` is not defined error message. Please help. I've made my code available here: http://pastebin.com/nkLRCmbZ